# Is it possible to do a UIBlurEffect on a black background

Tags: ios

My main view controller is very dark, and I want to do a blur effect popover when it's not doing the effect.[image: Something like this] But what is happening when I do is that everything turns black. I am doing this in storyboard

In my settingsvc view will appear

```
    UIBlurEffect *blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
    UIVisualEffectView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blur];
    blurView.frame = self.view.frame;

    [self.presentingViewController.view addSubview:blurView];
```

Comment: What does the view look like when it's not blurred?

Comment: That doesn't look like a popover.

Comment: @matt sorry not popover. Just presenting a view on top of the main.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg it's just plain black unless I add a low Alpha to it then I can see through it

Comment: Okay, well, your code makes no sense. The presenting view controller's view (your main view controller's view) is not in the interface, so there is no point adding a blur view to it. You need to write a custom presented view controller animation so that your Select Color view appears _on top of_ the main view controller.

Comment: No i am adding a blur to the settings view controller which appears on top of the main view controller